# Porque falla esta regex al intentar colocar un "0" si solo hay un numero pero no si son 2 o mas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, concatenación

```py
import re

input_text = "Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023"  #example 1
input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre"  #example 2
input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre"  #example 3

#for days
standard_number_of_digits_re_1 = r"(?:del dia|de el dia|del|de el|el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_2 = r"(\b\d{1}\b)[\s|]*º[\s|]*dia"

re_1_and_re_2 = r"(?:" + standard_number_of_digits_re_1 + r"|" + standard_number_of_digits_re_2  + r")"

#for months
standard_number_of_digits_re_3 = re_1_and_re_2 + r"(?:del mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_4 = re_1_and_re_2 + r"(?:del mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)[\s|]*(?:º[\s|]*mes del año|º[\s|]*mes)"


#El objetivo es poner un "0" delante de aquellos numeros de dias o meses en donde se les indico con una sola cifra y no con 2 cifras numericas
#  por ejemplo: '1' --> '01'  or  '10' --> '10'
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_3, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_4, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_1, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_2, r"0\1", input_text)


print(repr(input_text)) #output
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que las regex no parecen funcionar correctamente ya que no consigo hacer los reemplazos, pero probando en varios editores de codigo note estas 2 cosas:

- En la pagina https://regex101.com/r/1qLNEO/1  las regex aparentan atrapar a los grupos de texto correctos, pero aun asi dentro del código fallan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En el editor SublimeText, cuando coloco una `r` delante de `"(?:"` toda la linea inmediatamente se pone como si de una cadena de caracteres se tratase aunque se puede ver como esta cadena esta separada con operadores en medio encargados de la concatenación, sin embargo en StackOverflow esa linea si se visualiza correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si estas 2 observaciones son importantes en el mal funcionamiento de estas regex, pero por algun motivo que no encuentro las regex no logran extraer el texto para ser editado colocando (si el caso corresponde) un 0 delante.

Quedando los output deberían quedar de este modo al imprimirles:

```
"Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 08 de este año 2023"  #for example 1
"Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 07 de noviembre"  #for example 2
"Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 01º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 07º dia del mes de noviembre"  #for example 3
```

¿Qué modificaciones debería hacer para obtener estos resultados?

Comment: *no consigo hacer los reemplazos* ¿Cuales reemplazos? ¿Sabes el significado de "r" delante de una cadena? ¿Cual es el objetivo del ejercicio?

Comment: La `r` delante la coloque para que quede una backreference al valor del primer grupo de captura `group1`, que debe ser el numero. El objetivo es que por medio del método `re.sub()` (u otro método que logre obtener los output correctos) se consiga estandarizar los números de los días y los meses, para ello hice esas 4 regex cuya función es identificar el entorno en donde debe averiguarse que si hay un día o un mes indicado con una sola cifra numérica entonces que le agregue un `"0"` delante. Ahi al final de la pregunta coloque como deben quedar los 3 outputs para cada uno de esos 3 inputs.

Comment: Por ejemplo `"el 9º dia del mes 12"` debería quedar como `"el 09 dia del mes 12"`, o por ejemplo `"el dia 10 del 5"` debería quedar como `"el dia 10 del 05"`, estos reemplazos se hicieron porque cumplían tanto los patrones delante y despues del numero, ademas el numero era de una sola cifra. Notar que aunque en otros casos si se cumplió la regex delantera y posterior como el numero ya tenia 2 cifras, entonces no fue necesario agregar el `"0"` delante

Comment: Buen día, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr, ¿Deseas que los números siempre tengan por lo menos 2 dígitos y que en caso de aparecer el símbolo `°` sea eliminado? Si es así, por qué en tu respuesta deseada dice `para el 07º dia` ¿En qué casos sí se debe reemplazar y cuáles ignorar?

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con expresiones regulares?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato no debe eliminar el simbolo `º` porque aveces decimos `"el 1º de abril"` o `"el 1 de abril"`, y ambas expresiones son correctas, por lo que la regex lo que deberia hacer es si detecta esa secuencia `"el"` + `un numero` + `"(º|)"` deberia colocar el `"0"` delante del numero, para estandarizarlo a 2 cifras, en este caso quedaria `"01"`

Comment: @CandidMoe No es necesario que sea si o si por medio de regex, pero yo ya he planteado las 4 regex necesarias que por algun motivo en su lógica no funcionan, pero no habría problema en resolverlo de otro modo. Yo pense en usar regex porque creí que ayudaría a identificar los patrones que indican aquellas condiciones en que los reemplazos si deben hacerse. Yo he usado el metodo `re.sub()` para intentar reemplazar esas partes especificas, por ejemplo `"hay 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5"` debería agregarle un `"0"` delante del dia y del mes quedando `"hay 4 coches el dia 07 del mes 05"`

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez, pero los `regex` que tienes no funcionan como mencionas, no sé como sacaste la foto pero probando este `(\b\d{1}\b)[\s|]*º[\s|]*dia` en la misma página y con el mismo texto de prueba no hace `match` con nada

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Tienes razon, le di **F5** y no agarro nada, supongo que cuando antes le saque captura de pantalla la pagina se habría bugeado con un  resultado anterior, o algo asi, de todos si efectivamente eso esta fallando seria ese el error que tiene el código, de modo que debería agarrar lo que muestra la foto pero enrealidad no lo hace. Lo mas probable es que esta parte de la regex `(\b\d{1}\b)` tenga la culpa de ello.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sin expresiones regulares es esta función, que recibe una línea de texto y la retorna normalizando a dos dígitos los días:

```
def convertir(texto):
    palabras = texto.split()
    linea = []
    for i in range(len(palabras) - 1):
        palabra = palabras[i]
        if palabra[0].isdigit() and palabras[i+1] in ["del", "de", "mes", "dia"]:
            #   Caso de números en formato 1°.
            if palabra.endswith('º') and palabra[:-1].isnumeric():
                palabra = palabra[:-1]

            if palabra[0].isdigit():
                if len(palabra) == 1:
                    palabra = "0" + palabra

        linea.append(palabra)
    linea.append(palabras[-1])
    return ' '.join(linea)
```

La idea es recorrer las palabras buscando un número seguido de una palabra indicativa de fecha (de, del, día ...).

Cuando se da el caso, se chequea si el número termina en "°", y en tal caso, se quita.

El número que queda es normalizado a dos digitos y guardado en la lista de salida, junto a las otras palabras.

Al terminar el recorrido, armamos las frase uniendo los elementos de la lista.

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    "Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre",
    "Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023",
    "Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre",
    ]

def convertir(texto):
    palabras = texto.split()
    linea = []
    for i in range(len(palabras) - 1):
        palabra = palabras[i]
        if palabra[0].isdigit() and palabras[i+1] in ["del", "de", "mes", "dia"]:
            #   Caso de números en formato 1°.
            if palabra.endswith('º') and palabra[:-1].isnumeric():
                palabra = palabra[:-1]

            if palabra[0].isdigit():
                if len(palabra) == 1:
                    palabra = "0" + palabra

        linea.append(palabra)
    linea.append(palabras[-1])
    return ' '.join(linea)

for test in tests:
    nvo = convertir(test)
    print(test)
    print(nvo)
    print()
```

produce:

```
Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre
Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 01 mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 07 dia del mes de noviembre

Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023
Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 08 de este año 2023

Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre
Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 07 de noviembre


Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Segunda versión

Esta versión procesa también expresiones del tipo "mes x"

```
def convertir(texto):
    palabras = [' '] + texto.split() + [' ']
    linea = []
    for i in range(len(palabras) - 1):
        palabra = palabras[i]
        if palabra[0].isdigit():
            if palabras[i-1] == "mes" or palabras[i+1] in ["del", "de", "mes", "dia"]:
                #   Caso de números en formato 1°.
                if palabra.endswith('º') and palabra[:-1].isnumeric():
                    palabra = palabra[:-1]

                if palabra[0].isdigit():
                    if len(palabra) == 1:
                        palabra = "0" + palabra

        linea.append(palabra)
    return ' '.join(linea[1:])
```

produce:

```
hay 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5
hay 4 coches el dia 07 del mes 05

Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre
Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 01 mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 07 dia del mes de noviembre

Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023
Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 08 de este año 2023

Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre
Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 07 de noviembre


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias, la estaba probando y encontré un pequeño error con esta `"hay 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5"` que en lugar de quedar `"hay 4 coches el dia 07 del mes 05"` queda erróneamente como `"hay 4 coches el dia 07 del mes 5"`

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez. Veo que eres despierto. Te queda de tarea.

Comment: No te preocupes, muchísimas gracias igual. Lo único que no entendí de tu code, es sí este funciona haciendo un solo reemplazo de cada "tipo" de patrón, y si es por ello que falla en algo como `"hay 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5"`. Lo curioso es que si agrego la string `"del mes"` dentro de la lista `["del", "de", "mes", "dia"]` tampoco funciona, dejándome la duda si es por un limite de reemplazos posibles o si es que no podría tomar frases compuestas (con espacios en medio) ?

Comment: Esa lista contiene las palabras "después" del número. Tienes que agregar una condición: si la palabra actual es un número y la palabra anterior es "mes", entonces normalizar el número.

Comment: Yo habia apuntado a las regex por su capacidad generalizadora de varios casos, pero si intento con este método de recorrer palabras dentro de la string, deberia quedar la condición tan solo restándole `-1` para que sea la anterior a la palabra de la posición `i`, sin embargo modificando esto `if palabra[0].isdigit() and palabras[i-1] in ["del mes", "del dia", "del", "de", "mes", "dia"]:` no funciona esta especie de corrimiento dentro de la string y no entiendo porque

Comment: Las "palabras" no incluyen espacios ...

Comment: De todos modos ya dentro de esa lista esta la palabra `"mes"`, por lo que sigue siendo raro que no le tome